# Foreign key constraint with no from column

Tags: postgresql

In our database we happen to have a foreign key constraint that has an empty from column

It looks something like this

```
fk_1049376c154c25f8 FOREIGN KEY () REFERENCES table2 (id)
```

What does this denote and where is a documentation in the Postgres documentation for this

I see three possible meanings

- use the same column name as referenced in the second table so meaning `(id) references table2 (id)` implicitly
- use the primary key which would be id in this table so it might also be `(id) references table (id)`
- or monitor all columns `(*) references table2 (id)` which actually seems to be the way this behaves but does not make any sense to me in using it

Can anyone point me to a correct explanation or some read that confirms any of my theories or gives me the real truth?

Comment: Please show us the **complete** `create table` statement you are using

Answer (score 0):

Trying to use this throws a syntax error in PostgreSQL 9.3 at least.

```
postgres=# alter table test add foreign key () references test(id);
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ")"
LINE 1: alter table test add foreign key() references test(id);
```

I am guessing this comes from psql \d or something so it sounds like something wrong in your database, perhaps some sort of catalog corruption.

At any rate it is not a valid syntax and you should look into where this is coming from and fixing it.